# HTML tag to allow removable &nbsp

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

Does anyone know of a way to contain a nonbreaking space in an html tag to allow me to remove it based on conditions tested during runtime in the code behind?

Basically why I need this: if a condition is satisfied I will have 4 buttons, but if it's not only three.  I can remove the button but then I have 4 `&nbsp;` in-between 2 of the buttons instead of just 2 `&nbsp;`.

Something like the `<del>` tag would work if it didn't strike through the text.

Basically I have something like this(propery values not included for simplicity):

```
<td><button />&nbsp&nbsp<button />&nbsp&nbsp<button />&nbsp&nbsp<button /></td>
```

I can't have the function in the actual button tag because then it will render the &nbsp instead of the button text.

**EDIT**:
I did end editing the &nbsp tags out and using css.  I appreciate all of the responses.

The main reason that I was apprehensive to go that route to being with is because trying to get my client to approve anything is like pulling teeth, but I got them to approve the changes and adjust the budget.

Thanks again!!

Comment: Perhaps you could remove the `&nbsp;` characters altogether and use CSS `margin` for spacing.

Comment: You shoul not use `&nbsp;` for styling. Use CSS `margin` instead

Comment: I wish it was just that easy.  It would be inefficient as far as time goes.  See my comment below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does it need to be &nbsp;? Based on your description of the requirement, it sounds like a bit of CSS might work better:

```
  button.myClass {
    margin-left: 1ex;
  }
```

Much simpler than trying to put logic in your view layer (even if you are not strictly following the MVC pattern you should still try to separate your presentation and business logic as much as possible).

Comment: I'm in the middle of modifying someone else's project, and for the sake of consistency I need to stick with the &nbsp because it would be inefficient for me to go back and change everything to something else.  using css is my last resort, but I would rather not try to get approval for that.

Comment: Ugh. Maybe you could do something with the control tree in the render event: [link](http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1512/aspnet-page-life-cycle-events/). Don't tell anyone but I once did that in the past. Another option would be wrapping the button + space in another server-side div and then hiding/showing that. That would be, I think, cleaner and more consistent than mucking about with the control tree, which would be easy for a later developer to overlook.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `&nbsp;` for layout.

If you want to output some HTML content directly on the page without controls - you can use [Embedded Code Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178135.aspx):

```
<button/><% =GetNecessaryNbsp() %><button/>
```

Where GetNecessaryNbsp() in the page class would return necessary number  of `&nbsp;`.